# Assigning to Object variables within a method call

Tags: java, object

So when a method takes in an Object, I know that the Object's reference is passed, not the actual Object itself.

So when I assign a value to an Object inside the method, when the method call ends, the original Object is unchanged.

Is there a way to change the actual Object within a method call?

Comment: You can not re-assign that object, but you can changed the state by calling setters or other methods.

Comment: It sounds like you may have a misunderstanding, but your question isn't very clear.  It might help if you present some code to illustrate.

Comment: If you mean modifying the object's properties, then yes. You can't assign a value to an Object; you can change the variable holding the object's reference to point to another object (or nowhere), or use the variable to access the object it references.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to change exactly?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192226/what-is-the-best-practice-to-modify-an-object-passed-to-a-method

Comment: You want to change the referenced object or the value of the variable (the method parameter)?

Answer (score 0):

> So when a method takes in an Object, I know that the Object's reference is passed, not the actual Object itself.

This is incorrect. Everything is pass by value in Java. However when an object is passed, the values holds the reference of the actual object.

> So when I assign a value to an Object inside the method, when the method call ends, the original Object is unchanged.

This is incorrect too. The value in the original object will change when you pass the object to a method and change its value inside the method.

```
class Student{
    int age;   //To keep it simple, data is not private

    public Students(int age){
        this.age=age;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        Student s = new Student(17);
        addAge(s);
        System.out.println(s.age);      
    }
    public static void addAge(Students s){
        s.age += 5;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
22   //Age of original object does change
```

> Is there a way to change the actual Object within a method call?

It will change the actual object within a method call. In case you are wondering how do we not change the original object, then we will have to pass in a `copy` of the original.