# Return array vs fill array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, data-structures, return-value

I've seen two general types of methods whose goal is to return an array of values. The first is the most obvious:

```
public double[] getArray() {
    ...
    return ...;
}
```

However, I've also seen methods that fill arrays passed as arguments, such as `AffineTransform.getMatrix()`:

```
public void getMatrix(double[] flatmatrix) {
    ...
    flatmatrix[0] = ...;
    ....
}
```

What are the pros and cons of each method, and in which situations are each preferable? Also, what is the logic behind using the second method at all rather than just using the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason matrix methods prefer to modify arrays is that they are often used in graphics and draw calls. The way these are written allows reuse of an array.

It is desirable to not cause allocations inside a draw routine that is being called maybe 60 times a second. When this happens it causes more frequent garbage collections which can trigger a pause and the user can see some dropped frames.

Personally, I would refrain from copying the second technique unless it is for such performance reasons.

And if I decided I wanted to reuse and mutate an object, I would do so via methods on that object, OO style, instead of procedural style methods that modify inputs. e.g.

```
public class Matrix {
    public void setFromTransform(AffineTransform transform){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first method is better practice. The second method means you can "mutate" the argument flatmatrix and therefore cannot be sure what that matrix holds. Now if that's the desired behaviour (mutate the array), then second is more appropriate.

I tend not to mutate parameters, too error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

There are two opinions.

If you return an array - you have to create new array, as a result you spend more memory.

If you pass the array into method - you save memory and improve performance (due to Garbage Collecting). But it also violates [*Pure Function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) rule.

As for me, modifying input parameters, especially array is a very bad practice. The best way to avoid it is to encapsulate this logic into another class.

There are some informative questions about it:

- [Is modifying an incoming parameter an antipattern?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/245767/247285)
- [What is the best practice to modify an object passed to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192418/5091346)

Comment: But you have to create an array to pass one into the method too. e.g. `double[] matrix = new double[16]; getMatrix(matrix);` It only saves allocations if you can re-use the array in subsequent calls.

Comment: Thanks for those links; if I'd found them I probably wouldn't have asked my question! The memory saving logic was what I guessed, but I still thought it was weird when I found that method in AffineTransform. (Some io classes do the same thing, too) It also made it really hard to find what I was looking for in the JavaDoc, because I was looking for a method that returned double[] and instead found void.

Comment: If you pass or return a reference to an object like an array, then the recipient can modify the original object. If you copy the object then the recipient cannot modify the original object. Deep copies prevent modification of objects referenced by the passed instance. This is called "defensive copying" and is usually preferable where program correctness and maintainability is more important than microöptimization.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to return an array, this adds better decoupling.

Advantages of passing the array:

- Use the same array and reduce load on garbage collection

Disadvantages of passing the array:

- **Most Important:** In case of multithreaded  application if the passed array is shared with multiple threads then we need to make this array synchronized which would add performance overhead

Advantages of returning the array:

- Better decoupling as the caller has to just get the returned array and process it
- Caller does not need to pre-process, method just returns the resulting array (fill it with some fixed values or make it empty if this is needed)